# Multicurrency - getting in object and user currency

Tags: multi-currency

So Im looking at this page: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_currency_fields.htm

It really just says to use convertCurrency to get a currency in the users currency.

But objects can have a currency. So How do I get the value of the field in the user currency and the object currency in the same query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that's their third snippet?

```
SELECT Amount, FORMAT(amount) Amt, convertCurrency(amount) convertedAmount,
FORMAT(convertCurrency(amount)) convertedCurrency FROM Opportunity where id = '006R00000024gDtIAI'
```

You can reselect the currency column multiple times, and give it aliases (as above, with `Amount`, `Amt`, and `convertedAmount`) where the first is the original stored amount, the second being formatted nicely, and the last being in the user's currency.

Comment: Cool, I misunderstood that. Is there any way to check this in the developer console. When I try to use the alias, it just doesnt show the field being aliased.

Comment: When I use the query editor in the developer console, the query runs just fine, but the headers don't show the alias.  

E.g. `SELECT count(ID) ids, count(ContentDocumentId) names FROM ContentVersion` works ok.  That works fine in the execute anonymous block too, like so:
`
List<SObject> stuff = [SELECT count(ID) ids, count(ContentDocumentId) names FROM ContentVersion];
System.debug('ids: ' + stuff[0]);
`
Results in `10:14:28:007 USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|ids: AggregateResult:{ids=181, names=181}`
Not sure offhand what you'll have to do about casting the thing into something useful...

Comment: When I run the query Select Id, FORMAT(convertCurrency(Test_Currency__c)) convertedCurrency From Test_Object__c in the query editor I only get the Id back

Comment: Is there a value in `Test_Currency__c`?  What's the result of `Select Id, Test_Currency__c, FORMAT(convertCurrency(Test_Currency__c)) convertedCurrency From Test_Object__c`?

Comment: Yeah there is a value in there. It works fine with a debug from the Anonymous Window. I get the results I expect back. That will do I guess. There are 3 Test_Objects__c in the db. Each has a currency field with a value.

Comment: Ah, yea, that sounds good!  I don't often use the query editor, I do most of my stuff in Apex.  So maybe write a nice little service with a few unit tests, and you can utilize it with confidence.